# Разница между понятиями "элитный" и "элитарный"

Tags: лексика

Есть ли разница между понятиями "элитный" и "элитарный"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть -и принципиальная. У обоих слов по два значения, ни одна пара не совпадает.

ЭЛИТАРНЫЙ, -ая, -ое; -рен, -рна, -рно.
1.
Предназначенный для элиты (1 зн.). Э-ое образование. Освоение элитарных форм культуры. //
Состоящий из элиты, являющийся элитой (1 зн.). Э-ая часть общества.
2.
Изысканный, утончённый; доведённый до совершенства. Массовое и э-ое сознание. < Элитарность, -и; ж. Э. искусства. Э. воззрений.

ЭЛИТНЫЙ, -ая, -ое; -тен, -тна, -тно. Биол.
Представляющий собой элиту, являющийся элитой (2 зн.). Э-ая кукуруза. Э-ые семена. Э-ые лошади.
2.
Отборный, лучший, превосходный. Э-ые армейские подразделения. Э-ое жильё.*
©Кузнецов
//=========

Т.е. во-первых:
**Элитный** - представляющий собой элиту.
**Элитарный** - предназначенный для элиты.
И во-вторых:
**Элитный** - отборный, лучший, совершенный (при применении по назначению, по содержанию, деловым или производственным качествам)
**Элитарный** - изысканный, изящный, совершенный (по форме, эстетическим качествам).